# DynamoDB Schema Design - Order Model

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, key-value-store, nosql

I am modeling a simple application an I would like to use DynamoDB as my storage. I need to store a all order from a ecommerce website. It is possible to query using the order_id and the user email.

Looking at the dynamodb documentation, I think the best approach is to user the order_id (Most of my queries will be made on this index) as my primary key (Partition key).

And what about email? I would like a secondary index, but I am bit lost. 
What is the best approach?

Comment: what do you mean "What is the best approach?" . user email is a good secondary index (if you need to get certain users that ordered a order_id)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a **Global Secondary Index** on the `email` attribute would solve the problem:

- when you need to lookup by `order_id`, you use the `GetItem` operation and specify that `order_id` as the primary key
- when you need to lookup by `email`, you use the `Query` API on the GSI and specify the `email` as the partition key.

GSI have independent read capacity units - since you said you will use order_id most of the time, you could provision more RCU to the main table than the GSI.

Reference:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html